# Tic-tac-toe: Loading a save from a file

Tags: c, file

I have been trying to make a [tic-tac-toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) game, which prints out a board from the users input, and I have managed to save the boards current state, the grid's size, and the round count.
But when I try to load these data, for some reason I can't get the state of the board to be loaded from the .txt file.

```
void FileLoad(char ***Board, int *x, int *y, int *roundcount, const char *filename) {
    FILE *Load =fopen(filename, "r");
    if (Load == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        return;
    }

    fscanf(Load, "%d", *roundcount);
    fgetc(Load);
    fscanf(Load, "%d %d ", *x, *y);

    *Board = (char **)malloc(*y * sizeof(char *));

    (*Board)[0] = (char *)malloc((*y * *x) * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 1; i < *y; ++i)
         (*Board)[i] = (*Board)[0] + i * *x;

    fgetc(Load);

    for (int i = 0; i < *y; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *x; ++j)
            fscanf(Load, "%c", &(*Board)[i][j]);
        fgetc(Load);
    }
    fclose(Load);
}
```

With the debugger I found the problem's source is the last lines of the code when I try to get the data with an `fscanf`, but I don't know how can I fix that problem.

And this is how a Save file looks like on a 5*5 grid, with some placed characters. The first number is for the roundcount, the rest is for the grid for the board.

```
2
5 5
X

  O
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Can you provide an example of a file you are trying to load, and the *specific* problem you are having with it?

Comment: At first glance, your initial `fscanf()` calls are incorrect. The `%d` specifier requires a corresponding argument of type `int *` but you’re passing `int`s.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Re *"the problem's source"*: It could be made clearer by [adding](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77620511/edit) a comment to the code. (But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra `fgetc(Load)` before you load the board structure that is probably supposed to skip the pending newline but this newline was already consumed by `fscanf(Load, "%d %d ", ...)` because of the trailing space in the format string.

Also note that you must pass the pointers to `fscanf` instead of the values `*roundcount`, `*x` and `*y`.  Naming values and pointers to values with the same identifier is very confusing. To avoid this error prone method, use local variables for the values you read from the file and store them to the caller's variables only upon successful completion.

For easier troubleshooting, test all error cases and output an informative error message.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int FileLoad(char ***pboard, int *pcols, int *prows,
             int *proundcount, const char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "FileLoad: cannot open file %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    int rows, cols, roundcount;
    char eol[2];

    // read exactly 3 numbers and a newline.
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d%1[\n]", &roundcount, &cols, &rows, eol) != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "FileLoad: file %s: invalid format\n", filename);
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }

    char **board = (char **)malloc(rows * sizeof(char *));
    char *p = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * rows * cols));
    if (board == NULL || p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "FileLoad: file %s: allocation error\n", filename);
        free(board);
        free(p);
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        board[i] = p + i * cols;
    }

    // Read the game board
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            // should be a space, an 'X' or an 'O'
            board[i][j] = fgetc(fp);
        }
        if (fgetc(fp) != '\n') {
            fprintf(stderr, "FileLoad: file %s: invalid contents\n", filename);
            free(board);
            free(p);
            fclose(fp);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    *poard = board;
    *proundcount = roundcount;
    *pcols = cols;
    *prows = rows;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code still passes `*x` and `*y`.

Comment: @interjay: thank you for proofreading. These names were quite confusing anyway. I amended the answer with more explanations and a more robust modified version.